# SonarQube + Jacoco - Unable to read Koin module test coverage

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, koin

I'm having some issues when trying to import Jacoco code coverage to sonar, this is happening to all Koin modules.

**Sonar version:** 7.5.0.20127

**Jacoco version:** 0.8.2

Erro:

```
       ERROR: Cannot import coverage information for file 'mmaccount/src/main/java/br/com/project/mmaccount/di/AccountModule.kt', coverage data is invalid. Error: {}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 84 is out of range in the file mmaccount/src/main/java/br/com/project/mmaccount/di/AccountModule.kt (lines: 83)
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.coverage.internal.DefaultCoverage.validateLine(DefaultCoverage.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.coverage.internal.DefaultCoverage.lineHits(DefaultCoverage.java:81)
```

And because of this, my module class is with 0% of o coverage, but if I look the HTML report it seems to work fine:

[Jacoco HTML report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iAgv.png)

This is happening only with my Koin modules, I'm not sure if the problem is how Koin works or some incompatibility between Jacoco and Kotlin

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, it seem it was an issue of jacoco when generating the report, more info on this issue: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/763

**The solution:** upgrade to **0.8.3** that was release with that issue fixed.

With the new version of jacoco now my classes that had zero coverage on sonar now have the real coverage.